# Facebook: How to get friends' check ins with Graph Api?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, checkin

This question was asked a couple of times but, there is no clear answer for me. I am developing an app and I want to fetch check ins of user's friends. How do I do this with graph api or without it?

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: You can't. The API only give you access to the information of the user that logged into your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access Friend checkins anymore, the permission for it (`friends_checkins`) has been removed from Graph API v2.0+. In fact, all friend related permissions have been removed.

The only way to find check-in information now is to check the Facebook Stream by calling, and looking for checkin information:

```
/me/home
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have wasting my time since morning